# Query Data from an Event Table in ArcGIS (Linear Referencing)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql-server, linear-referencing

My goal is to store a bunch of past present and future Events in a central place from different vehicles, query those tables on demand and display the result in ArcMap. Note that right now, my Route Reference is a shapefile stored locally

I have started small by loading a simple excel file containing Events and I could display them rather easily using Display Route Event in ArcMap. Unfortunately, I cannot query this table because the table doesn't have an Object-ID (error message from ArcMap). The only option is to convert the table into a shapefile or feature class. By doing so, not only does it add an extra step but I also lose the "live feed" from my table which is something I have to keep.

I have tried with a DB Connection (data have been loaded into an SQL Server instance) hoping I could Add Query Layers to be displayed as route event as well. I'm running into some issues there as well (licence level related I think) but it seems to be the way.

Maybe there's a better solution to reach my goal within ArcGis or QGIS. I could establish a connection between QGIS and SQLSERVER but couldn't find a way to query the database (tried through DB Manager but only spatial lite and postgis available). I guess the ideal is to have everything stored in Postgres postgis and use DB Manager. Unfortunately I have to work with SQL Server

Comment: Have you tried loading the excel spreadsheet as a table in the geodatabase and using that.  You should be able to query a geodatabase table.  Then, if you really had to for some reason, I guess you could even write a python script and schedule it that would delete the rows from that loaded table and re-load the up-dated rows from the spreadsheet if they absolutely have to be maintained in the spreadsheet, not in the GDB.  Not perfect, but hope it helps.